# How does evaopration and diffusion affect concentration of solute at the solvent surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion, evaporation, chemical-potential, transport-phenomena

Imagine a long, thin tube with one end sealed and the other end open. It is filled with a volatile solvent with a dissolved non-volatile solute. As the solvent evaporates at the liquid surface, the solvent level falls and the concentration of solution there will increase. This sets up a concentration gradient, leading to diffusion according to Fick's Laws. In this case, convection generated from the concentration gradient can be ignored as the solution is considered to be dilute.

I have found a [paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2018/cp/c8cp00305j) one this topic. In equation 6, the solute flux $J$ at position $z$ and time $t$ is stated, though for a slightly different system than the one I described.

$$J\left(z,t\right)=-v\left(t\right)\phi\left(z,t\right)-\frac{D\left(\phi\right)}{RT}\phi\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial z}$$

where $D$ is the diffusivity, which is a function of concentration $\phi$. $\mu$ represents chemical potential of the solvent and $v$ is the flow velocity of the medium at $z$.

There are two main parts where I am confused.

One, the system that is modelled in the paper is different to the one I am interested in. In the paper, one end of the tube is open for fresh solution to flow in to keep the volume constant, whereas I am interested in the case where the tube is sealed on one end, causing the solvent level to slowly fall. In that case, how should the above equation be modified?

Two, I do not understand what role $\mu$ is playing in this equation and whether it is applicable to the system I described above.

I apologise in advance if there are already answers to my question elsewhere as I am new to the field of transport phenomena and thermodynamics.

Comment: Is the convection triggered by density gradient ruled out?

Comment: See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al, third section on Mass Transfer

Comment: @Poutnik Yes, I have also edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ChetMiller The book is not freely available, I have heard it mentioned quite a lot. Could you please summarise that chapter and explain it to me since I am very new to the subject?

Comment: It's too much to cover in this kind of format.

Comment: @ChetMiller I see. Then would it be possible to at least give me the equation with governs the concentration of solute and explain that? I can research the rest myself.